# How can I make my git changes visible in production mode (Symfony)?

Tags: symfony, production

1. I make changes local on my mac in dev mode.
2. After committing the changes I login via ssh to my server.
3. There I make the command `git pull`

Now I see my changes on my webpage.

Unfortunately this only works in `dev` mode.

When I change the mode to production mode in my .env file, then I do not see any updates. What can I do?

Comment: sudo -u www-data bin/console cache:clear

Comment: What else did you try to resolve the problem? Without knowing anything about the changes, it's close to impossible to provide help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command solved the problem:

```
rm -rf var/cache/
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to clear the cache. This can be done with the following command :

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: I tried, but it did not work. What finally worked was `rm -rf var/cache/`

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

to be sure

If you use phpfpm on your server, it can also be required to restart phpfpm service after the cache:clear.

**This should not** be used in production environemment :

```
rm -rf var/cache
```